# how to use a webservice which created on c#t at java platform

Tags: java, .net, web-services, jsp

Previous developers created a webproject which consumes a webservice in .net platform and they wanted me to use this webservice on jsp. I read netbeans tutorials and find out that  webservice is irrelevant to platform. However the problem is at .net project I could not find a file whose extension is .wsdl or a werbservice.amsx.There is a service.cs which was implemented has webservice commands a lot.How i can consume or use this service on a jsp file? I would be appreciated if you can help me. Because it takes my hours to read documentations and I do not have any clue how to use it on .jsp.

Best Regards
Altaico

Comment: Don't create new post for each information you want to provide. Modify your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/WSIntegration02132006041221AM/WSIntegration.aspx) detailed tutorial on C-sharpcorner.com on how to reference and use asmx web services in JSP

Comment: Hi

there is webservice.asmx file neither webxml file in the directory? There are only .cs files in the director? Do you think everything is created successfully? I am looking forward for your replies. Thank you so much from now.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For Web Services in general to function correctly you need to have a WSDL.  Most modern web service stacks can generate these automatically.

Have a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the asmx file from your browser with ?wsdl query string.